# How to get all view on a selected area of screen in Android

Tags: android, screen, object-detection, draw, rect

I am working on a project android.
I selected a area of screen, then all view in this area (textview, button, edittext...) will be highlight on each rect shape.

How I do that?

Comment: You mean in designer or at run time?

Comment: Hello, I mean run on time